# Change colors while maintining intensity of the original color in Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, color-space, hsv

I want to change the color of a bulldozer to a specific Hexadecimal color (red in this case)
[image: Original image]
while preserving the intensity (the effect of light on the bulldozer).
I want to change only the yellow parts of it, so far I have created a mask with a lower and upper bounds for the light and darker yellow tones, and extracted that mask, however I don't know how to apply the color red to the mask and keep the relative intensity of the color, not just all the same tone of red.

Something like the following image would be great (better quality if possible, since there seems to be some color not correctly set)
[image: expected result]

I have seen some workarounds using HSV but nothing really does the job.

My code so far involves creating a mask to extract the color that I want to change and convert that mask to HSV colors to preserve the intensity of the colors, after that I try to modify the HSV to achieve the desired color, however it is not precise, there is no exact way to change the HSV to the hexadecimal or rgb color that I want?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import math
from numpy import inf

# set the bounds for the light and dark shade of color you want to mask
lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100])
upper_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])  

all_images = sorted(os.listdir('data/audi_a6'))
for i, image in enumerate(all_images):
    print(image, end='\r')
    img = cv2.imread(f'data/lego/{image}')
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)
    inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(yellow_mask)

    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    h = np.mod(h - h + 182, 180)
    s = np.clip(s + 120, 0, 255)
    v = np.clip(v, 0, 255)
    hsv = cv2.merge([h, s, v])

    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    result = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=inv_mask), cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, bgr, mask=yellow_mask))

    # Save the result
    cv2.imwrite(f'output_change_color/lego/frame_{i:03}.jpg', result)
```

Comment: Please add your code to make a proper [mcve].

Comment: I have added my code so far, it works but to actually set the color that I want is not possible. @Mark Setchell

Comment: You've gone very quiet. Did you have any success with our answers? Or are there still issues?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having difficulty discriminating between the yellow machine and the *"muddy track"* beneath it. One way to work out these things is to look at different colourspaces and see which one is a good discriminant. So, I converted your image to many different colourspaces and split out the individual channels side-by-side for you:

[image]

So you could look at each channel of each colourspace and see which one works best for you. For example the third channel of `CIELab`, or the second channel of `HCL`...

Comment: That is great insights! nice visualization too, but my issue is more on the coloring part than on the segmentation of the mask itself. I want to be able to change the yellow color to whichever color I want given an rgb or hexadecimal color code, if that makes sense. 
The blue picture provided is actually pretty good, but I am unsure on how to achieve the same for the red color hsv[0, 90, 90] without manually trying hundreds of combinations until one approaches the desired color. I have tried changing the h, s, v values to 0, 90, 90 respectively but the output is not good.

Comment: How about retaining the Value and Saturation from the original but just replacing the Hue? If you receive the new colour in RGB, just change that to HSV as well to get the Hue. Also, there's nothing to stop you segmenting in one colourspace (and getting a mask) and then replacing in another colourspace using the mask.

Comment: I have also tried only manipulating the hue value. 
    h = np.mod(h - h + 182, 180),  
    s = np.clip(s, 0, 255),  
    v = np.clip(v, 0, 255),  
however the color is still not even close to the HSV representation of hsv(0, 90%, 90%)

Comment: I'm in a rush, but remember that OpenCV stores Hues with ***half*** the expected value you might see elsewhere so that 360 degrees of hue can fit in a `uint8` which can only support 0..255. So, if you want Hues around, say, 80, you would use 40 in OpenCV. Alternatively, you can change your image type to `float` then it can use the regular 0...360 range.

Comment: wouldn't using the mod (% 180) as I do in the example fix that to an 8 bit variable as a workaround to halving the the hue value?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one thing I need to do to get your code to produce the expected result. The H channel is around 25 for the yellow pixels. We want it to be 0 instead. So we need to subtract 25: `H - H_yellow + H_red`.

But since `h` is a `uint8` array, subtracting 25 will cause some pixels to wrap around to 255, which is not a valid value for H (OpenCV defines it in the 0-180 range for 8-bit images). So instead if adding 0 we add 180, then the `np.mod()` operation can do the right thing:

```py
h = np.mod(h + 180 - 25, 180)
```

This is obviously not generic. To do this more generically, we're better off using floating-point operations for arithmetic, as there's no overflow or wrapping to worry about. This has another advantage: OpenCV won't quantize the HSV space to integer values, which allows for a more precise reconstruction. But remember that H is now in the range 0-360, and S and V in the range 0-1.

```py
img = cv2.imread(image)

imgf = img.astype(np.float32) / 255
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imgf, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

h = np.mod(h + h_target - h_source, 360)
s = np.clip(s + s_taget - s_source, 0, 1)

hsv = cv2.merge([h, s, v])
imgf = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
bgr = (imgf * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

[Note we don't touch V.]

Comment: I assume that h_target and s_target represent the red color I want, what values are h_source and s_source exactly? I believe they correspond to the original yellow color (in this case) but those values of h and s how would I obtain them when my only data are the lower and upper bounds?

Comment: @diegobc11 I assume your user would specify “convert yellow to red”, so you know the HS values of those two colors. If all you have is the bounds of the colors, take the mean of the bounds, or take the mean of the image within those bounds. Many ways to solve this.

Comment: We only have this yellow image as input and want to change the yellow parts to a red color whose code is hsv(0, 90%, 90%), so essentially we only have the H and S values for the second color

Comment: @diegobc11 Try with `h_source = np.mean(h[yellow_mask])`. Or just set `h_source` and `s_source` to some prototypical yellow color.